# Network Traffic in Google Chrome Arc Welder

Tags: android, debugging, google-chrome-arc

Ok, I'm sure I'll get a downvote or two for this vague question... but help a novice out. Thanks in advance.

I am attempting to QA/debug an application to verify HTTP requests are being made to various analytics endpoints correctly.

- I am using Arc Welder to run an Android apk.
- I've got Chrome open, using `chrome://inspect` and seeing Console output. So far so good. [image: Console activity looks OK]
- But on the Network tab, I don't see any actual traffic, just requests for the same static assets whenever the app goes from active to background and back. [image: Network activity, not so much]

Ideas?